# selinux blocks user from listening ports < 32768 (no, it's > 1024)

Tags: linux, centos, selinux

I was trying to get a nodejs server up, found that it fails to bind port 8000 or 8080, 1234, 12345....

```
Error: listen EACCES
```

It works if I disable selinux (echo 0 > /selinux/enforce) or if I run it as root.

Is it a nodejs thing? python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 fails too.

```
socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Then I tried port 54321, and it works, 32768, works, 32767, nope.
Ok, so both python and nodejs will work if

```
the port > 32767
```

or

```
selinux disabled
```

or

```
has root privilege
```

Both node and python are installed to /usr/bin via yum install.

```
-rwxr-xr-x. root root   system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       node
-rwxr-xr-x. root root   system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       python
```

Which selinux policy is causing this?

It's an updated Centos 6.4 x64 minimal box.

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to see if the port is open in SELinux with:

```
semanage port -l | grep 8000
```

If it's not in the list you can try to open that port with:

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 8000
```

Comment: I tried that with 433 and nginx still cannot bind unless I put selinux into permissive, wait until the port is bound and then put selinux back to enforcing. Am I missing a command to apply the setting?